# Trouble displaying MYSQL Results

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve an entire row of data from my database for the user that is currently logged into my website. I then want to take the data and store each field into a variable, so that I can call any one of those variables and display it anytime I want it anywhere on my page. The problem I'm having is I keep getting an the following error

```
ERROR

Notice: Undefined variable: User_Info in C:\wamp\www\PhotographyConferenceSite\Users\account.php on line 129
```

Line 129 is where I am attempting to test my code, and call a single variable to be printed.
It says the variable is undefined yet, this should not be the case.

Here PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) // This section is working I included it to show where my variable in my query is created.
{
$curUser = $_SESSION['username']; // curuser is valid as it is called on my html page and it works properly
$titleMessage = "You are logged in as: ";

$topNavSlot1Txt = "<li> Logout </li>";
$topNavSlot1Link = "../Login_System/logout.php";
}
else
{
header('Location: ../Login_System/login.php');
}

//CALLS DATA FOR THE ARRAY/GIVE ITS CONDITIONS
$user_data ="SELECT `User_Name`, `Email`, `First_Name`, `Middle_Initial`, `Last_Name`, `Phone`, `Cell_Phone`, `Address_1`, `Address_2`, `City`, `Zipcode`, `State`, `Country`, `Attendee`, `Referred_By`, `Skill_Level`, `Club_Member`, `Club_One`, `Club_Two`, `Club_Misc`, FROM `members` WHERE User_Name='$curUser'"; // where condition is calling a session vairable

$UDD = mysqli_query($db_server, $user_data);

if($UDD)
{
while( $User_Info = mysqli_fetch_array($UDD)) // Sets the retrived data to an array
{
    // declares the arrays variables

    $User_Info['User_Name'];
    $User_Info['Email'];
    $User_Info["First_Name"]; // THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO TEST.
    $User_Info['Middle_Initial'];
    $User_Info['Last_Name'];
    $User_Info['Phone'];
    $User_Info['Cell_Phone'];
    $User_Info['Address_1'];
    $User_Info['Address_2'];
    $User_Info['City'];
    $User_Info['Zipcode'];
    $User_Info['State'];
    $User_Info['Country'];
    $User_Info['Attendee'];
    $User_Info['Referred_By'];
    $User_Info['Skill_Level'];
    $User_Info['Club_Member'];
    $User_Info['Club_One'];
    $User_Info['Club_Two'];
    $User_Info['Club_Misc'];
}
}
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
  <div id="accountInfo"> <!-- info for registration. -->
         Did you change your phone? Move? Need a new password?
         You can change your account information here!!! <br /> <br />     

          previous data  

          TESTING : <span> <?php echo $User_Info["First_Name"]; ?></span> <!-- LINE 129! ERROR FOUND HERE.-->
         </div> <!-- end of registration info --> <!-- info for registration. -->
```

NOTE: I've removed extra code that does not apply to this problem. Line 129 has been commented to find it. Also both pieces of code are on the same page. I should also mention while I did not include my connection info, the connection to the database is also working.

Any Help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `$User_Info['First_Name']`instead of `$User_Info["First_Name"]`

Comment: I tried this, however there was no difference the error still appeared.

Comment: three things come on my mind, 1) use lower case $User_Info["first_name"]. and 2) try var_dump($User_Info) and see what the array actually holds. 3) is all your code in one context? try to make $User_Info global

Comment: Does `First_Name` have a value in the database? If it is set to `null` it won't be returned by your `mysqli_fetch_array()` call and that element of your array won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli_query will only return false if there if there is a SQL error. Replace the if on the result:

```
// Use
if (mysqli_num_rows ( $UDD ) > o)

// Instead of 
if($UDD)
```

It looks like your query is returning an empty set so $UDD is set to true rather than a result set.

Comment: I just noticed I wrote a o when I meant to use a 0 on the conditional statement, doh!

Comment: I just tried this however, this does not fix the error, it actually gave me a second one. Is there another part of the code that needs to be changed in order for this to work? (I caught the o error anyways np)

Comment: Do you have a way to test your query directly on the DB? phpmyadmin or just the command line? Echo out the query after the variable has been put into it then test that it does return results when ran directly on the DB